# How to limit a JQuery effect to one Element within a nested block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an H1 tag that contains text and an image.  The tag looks something like this:

```
<h1 id="title">My Title
    <img class="image" src="/icons/image.png">
</h1>
```

I have some CSS:

```
#title{
    position:absolute;
    font-family:"Papyrus";
    color:purple;
    font-size:80px;
    left: 42%;
    margin-top:-.1%;
}

.image{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-120px;
    margin-top:35px;
}
```

I have nested these two so that the image stays with the h1 tag as the screen is re-sized.

What I would like to do is have two different JQuery effects run simultaneously; however, the ".image" portion is getting caught up in the effect of the "#title".  The Jquery looks like this:

```
$("#title").hover(function(){
    $("#title").effect("puff","slow",function(){
        $("#title").fadeIn()});
    $(".image").effect("bounce","slow");
});
```

What appears to happen is that the image class gets pulled into the puff effect which I don't want.  It then does the bounce effect but it does it far away from its normal spot.  I think it does this perhaps based on the the extended puff location but I am not sure.  Regardless, I want the puff effect to only act on the #title and not the .image portion.

Thanks.

Comment: Effects are really just javascript that changes certain CSS properties, and you can't change the CSS of the parent and expect the child element to not be affected, it moves with the parent, so what you're trying to do is impossible unless you figure out a way to do it without nesting the elements.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  The only reason I am nesting the elements is to keep them together if the user re-sizes the browser.  Is there perhaps a better way to accomplish that without nesting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the image outside of the heading and into a div. You might need to apply some additional styling, but this is probably your best option.

```
<div>
    <h1 id="title">My Title</h1>
    <img class="image" src="/icons/image.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried this earlier but could not get it to work right.  However, since there was not an easy JQuery solution I went back to it at your suggestion and was able to get it to work with additional CSS.  Essentially I made the div absolute with a percentage margin.  I made the other elements within it absolute as well but with px margins.  This allows some fluid design in the re-size without moving the image where I didn't want it.  When the screen is sized too small I use a media query to adjust.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Do not nest them. Instead use absolute positioning to make them appear to be overlapped.

Comment: I did use absolute positioning as you can see from the CSS, however, if the window is re-sized the image and the h1 text separate.  By nesting them I am able to keep them together during a re-size.